# Good EE5 single sign-on solutions?

Tags: ee5, single-sign-on

I'm considering implementing EE5 with SSO. Does anybody have experience or recommendations for this? I've found a miniOrange solution https://www.miniorange.com/expressionengine-single-sign-on-(sso) that might be good--any comments on that?

Comment: The initial question would be what is your source of truth when it comes to identity authentication? Do you want miniOrange to be central to that, or do you already have another identification authority (such as Active Directory) you need to work with? Or is open authentication a solution (oAuth)?

Comment: I have an identification authority that's offering SSO/Active Directory authentication, but I don't know if this could work with EE. That is, instead of the standard login at /admin.php against the EE database, the user authenticates with SSO from this authority, then is also authenticated as an EE user and taken to the control panel.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is simply to allow other authentication schemes to act as mechanisms for gaining access to EE, you might get what you need from the "[Social Sign In](https://addons.reinos.nl/social-sign-in)" plugin from Reinos.nl

This does not offer access to the full SSO universe, but potentially covers a large proportion of it.

I have not used this plugin, but can recommend Reinos stuff in general, and commend them for providing good support too: unusual for an EE addon in my experience.

HTH

Comment: Could be too Smart Members Pro : https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/smart-members-pro